# Bullseye python2 RPi.GPIO

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-2.x, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

As I read from forums, Python2 is removal at bullseye. I install python2.7 manually but there is gpio problem with python2.

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

dont work. Raises

```
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

And very long error log.
Do you have any suggestions?

Edit:

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python2.7 -m pip install pyparsing
sudo python2.7 -m pip install pyparser
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev
sudo apt-get install clang
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

used and still dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo CFLAGS="-fcommon" pip install RPi.GPIO
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: Why are you still using Python2?

Comment: I just don't want to port all my python2 codes to python3..

Comment: Congratulations for resolving your issue, and posting the answer here - that helps others. ICYI, you can "accept" your own answer - but you might have to wait a day or two before the system allows you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, when upgrading a particularly old system from Stretch through Buster to Bullseye and the Bullseye upgrade broke a script I had running.  `sudo apt install python3-rpi.gpio` is what you want to upgrade to the Python 3 version of RPi.GPIO.